# OAcurl access token expires in hour or so

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-search-console

I am using OAcurl to fetch sitemap, clicks etc using Google Webmaster API.

To do so i followed steps from https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/quickstart/quickstart-oacurl

Problem is that to run step 4 i have to go through step 3 (in case i am accessing it after 1-2 hours). It means i have to click allow everytime in browser to run api, which means i can't set cron and sit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using some language library for Google Search Console (python, ruby, php etc.):

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/samples

Refresh your tokens automatically using such libraries.

Comment: I already started with PHP library, but thanks bro for replying. Its correct answer.